# Recyclerview call contacts Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I have an android app where I have used RecyclerView that shows a list of contacts. Now what I want is that when selecting the contacts, call the indicated number.

For now all it do is show the contacts, but when i click on it it calls, it does not do any action. I do not know how to get it to mark

I tried with `onClick()` and with button item.But Unsuccessful

**My code:**

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private static final String TAG = "RecyclerViewAdapter";

    Context mContext;
    List<Contact> mData;
    Dialog myDialog;
    Button button;



    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context mContext, List<Contact> mData) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mData = mData;
    }



    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View v ;
        v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.single_item_contact,parent,false);
        final MyViewHolder vHolder = new MyViewHolder(v);

        // Dialog ini

        myDialog = new Dialog(mContext);
        myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_contact);
        myDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));





        vHolder.item_contact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               // Toast.makeText(mContext,"Text Click item : "+String.valueOf(vHolder.getAdapterPosition()),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                TextView dialog_name_tv = (TextView) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_name_id);
                TextView dialog_phone_tv = (TextView) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_phone_id);
                ImageView dialog_contact_img = (ImageView)myDialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_img);
                dialog_name_tv.setText(mData.get(vHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getName());
                dialog_phone_tv.setText(mData.get(vHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getPhone());
                dialog_contact_img.setImageResource(mData.get(vHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getPhoto());


                myDialog.show();
            }
        });


        return vHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        holder.tv_name.setText(mData.get(position).getName());
        holder.tv_phone.setText(mData.get(position).getPhone());
        holder.img.setImageResource(mData.get(position).getPhoto());



    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private LinearLayout item_contact;
        private TextView tv_name;
        private TextView tv_phone;
        private ImageView img;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            item_contact = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.contact_item_id);
            tv_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_contact);
            tv_phone = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.phone_contact);
            img = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_contact);

        }
    }
}
```

Aquí muestro mi XML de como tengo.
help please

```
    <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="#232323"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dialog_name_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
            android:text="Contact Name"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dialog_phone_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="Phone Number"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="23sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dialog_btn_call"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/dialog_call_black"
            android:drawablePadding="20dp"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:text="Llamar"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:textSize="25dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dialog_btn_msg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/dialog_message_black"
            android:drawablePadding="20dp"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:text="Mensaje"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            android:textSize="25dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_img"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_contacts"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what exactly you want ? you need to call to selected contact ?

Comment: Just put your `vHolder.item_contact.setOnClickListener` code block in `OnBindViewHolder`

Comment: I think you should check below link [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471109/recyclerview-onclick)

Comment: Yes, I want the selected contact to call your number

Comment: Use Following code:-  String number = "1234"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
      Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" +number));
    startActivity(intent);  add permission in manifest file as:-  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>

Comment: crashed the application with this code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put setOnClickListener() into OnBindViewHolder().So far what i understand is you have Recycler View in which on item click you want to open a dialog box **dialog_contact** and this dialog box contains Contact information. After opening this dialog you want to call that person by clicking call button present in dialog.

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        holder.tv_name.setText(mData.get(position).getName());
        holder.tv_phone.setText(mData.get(position).getPhone());
        holder.img.setImageResource(mData.get(position).getPhoto());

        holder.item_contact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

             myDialog = new Dialog(mContext);
             myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_contact);
             myDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));    

             myDialog.show();

             TextView dialog_name_tv = (TextView)myDialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_name_id);
             Button dialog_btn_call= (Button )myDialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_btn_call);
             TextView dialog_phone_tv = (TextView) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_phone_id);
             ImageView dialog_contact_img = (ImageView)myDialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_img);
             dialog_name_tv.setText(mData.get(vHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getName());
             dialog_phone_tv.setText(mData.get(vHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getPhone());
             dialog_contact_img.setImageResource(mData.get(vHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getPhoto());

            dialog_btn_call.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
             //Do your code here
                myDialog.dismiss();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" +mData.get(holder.getAdapterPosition()).getPhone()));
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
             }
             }); 


            }
        });


    }
```

**Edit:-**

Comment: I get errors in vHolder, is it a field?
and error in activity.startActivity (intent);
please help

Comment: Sorry , it will be holder , i have edited my answer. Put holder instead of vHolder

Comment: use this mContext.startActivity(intent) in your case.

Comment: Thanks, if it works.
There is some way to make the call directly without going through the stock application?

Comment: No, It well open your default dialer directly. Happy to hear it helped.You can upvote and accept this then.

Comment: Another quick question. Select the LinearLayout and make the call.
But I want the button ("dialog_btn_call") to be the one making the call

Comment: Do your linear layout contains dialog_btn_call button?

Comment: Yes, it contains a button and from there I want you to call

Comment: Thank you very much. You're the best.

Comment: Pleasure is all mine :)

Comment: Can you help me in this other example? Please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50051749/call-contacts-from-a-list-in-android-studio